# How center a Navigation Bar Image [Swift]

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

in my project I have a Navigation Bar with a Button to open a slide menu.
Now I am trying to set a title image instead of the title string. Unlikely the image is pushed slightly to the right instead of being centered. I thought its because of the slide menu button in the left corner of my navigation bar. If I set a title in main.storyboard everything look properly. Why is it so, that my image won't be centered.

Image function:

```
func addNavBarImage() {

    let navController = navigationController!

    let image = UIImage(named: "TransparentLogo")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
    let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

    let bannerX = bannerWidth - image!.size.width
    let bannerY = bannerHeight - image!.size.height
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```

Button function:

```
func addSlideMenuButton(){
    let btnShowMenu = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
    btnShowMenu.setImage(self.defaultMenuImage(), for: UIControl.State())
    btnShowMenu.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    btnShowMenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BaseViewController.onSlideMenuButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    btnShowMenu.tintColor = UIColor(red: 3, green: 49, blue: 79)
    let customBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnShowMenu)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;

}
```

Comment: An image of what you currently get and what you would like to achieve would be really helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the frame of your titleView in func `addNavBarImage()` like this:-

```
func addNavBarImage() {

let navController = navigationController!

let image = UIImage(named: "TransparentLogo")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

let bannerX = bannerWidth - image!.size.width
let bannerY = bannerHeight - image!.size.height
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```

to this

```
func addNavBarImage() {
let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "TransparentLogo"))
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 170, height: 30)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 170, height: 30))

titleView.addSubview(imageView)
titleView.backgroundColor = .clear
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
}
```

Comment: How can I make it a little bigger though?

Comment: change width and height ;) as per your requirement but you can't make more large because navigation bar has fixed height

Comment: By doing that the image is moving to the right again -.- :D

Comment: maybe its because we can't change it more :D https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar read about it

Comment: Yeah I will do so

Answer (score 0):

```
func centeredNavBarImageView() {
    if let navcontroller = navigationController {
        let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        let bannerWidth = navcontroller.navigationItem.accessibilityFrame.size.width
        let bannerHeight = navcontroller.navigationBar.frame.size.height
        let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - image.size.width / 2
        let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - image.size.height / 2

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }
```